# For any $n\times n$ matrix, the set of $\{x | x^T Mx \le c\}$ is a closed set.

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

I'm trying to prove that for any $n \times n$ matrix $M,$ for any $c>0$, the set of $S=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:x^TMx\le c\}$ is a closed set.

I have tried to expand the matrix into the function, however, it doesn't help at all. And I don't remember there is any properties to apply to all square matrix.

Can someone give a hint?

Comment: Suggest writing it all out for the $2 \times 2$ case. Maybe you can see why it's a closed set in that case, and get some ideas.

Comment: $f(x) = x^t Mx$ is a continuous function.

Comment: @hugod I do see that this is a linear mapping, but I believe only if the transformation is invertible, then a closed set $\mathbb R ^ n$ can transform to a closed set S.

Comment: It is not linear. Also note that,  $$\{ x: \, x^TMx>c\}= f^{-1}(c,+\infty)$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** The inverse image of a closed set under continuous function is closed. The function $f:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=x^TMx \ \ \forall x\in\mathbb R^n $ is continuous.